# Setting password for samba user on RHEL7

Tags: samba, rhel7

I am working on RHEL7 instance and my requirement is to add Samba user and set the password for it through bash script.

I'd able to add samba user but getting an error while setting a password.

Here is an error I am getting.

smbpasswd: relocation error: /lib64/libsamba-credentials.so.0: symbol GSS_KRB5_CRED_NO_CI_FLAGS_X, version gssapi_krb5_2_MIT not defined in file libgssapi_krb5.so.2 with link time reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `libgssapi_krb5.so.2` is too old.

Try

```
yum upgrade
```

Similar to what described at

- [testparm fails with: relocation error: /lib64/libsamba-credentials.so.0: symbol GSS_KRB5_CRED_NO_CI_FLAGS_X, version gssapi_krb5_2_MIT not defined in file libgssapi_krb5.so.2 with link time reference](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1367316)
- [smbclient error in Mounting CIFS and NFS Network File Systems Learning Lab](https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/12076-smbclient-error-in-mounting-cifs-and-nfs-network-file-systems-learning-lab)

Answer (score 0):

"Yum upgrade" didn't solve my problem.
I'd installed krb5-server and krb5-libs before samba and then it worked for me.

First I installed ntp then started it and then I used "yum -y install krb5-server krb5-libs" to get it worked.

Cheers,
Ashvini